# OAuth Auth Code Flow and SSO Initiated by API Provider

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect

For this flow, the user (resource owner) starts in the UI of the API Provider (resource server). The aim is to transfer the user to an oauth client UI where the client app will be able to call APIs in the originating resource server. Note the client app is likely to be closely affiliated with the API Provider (e.g. a cloud service that has the same owner as the API Provider). An option is to send the user to the  client which then initiates the usual auth code flow process, but it seems that this could be streamlined by just redirecting to the redirect_uri from the resource server to begin with. Probably best shown by a comparison of the two flow:

Standard OIDC OAuth SSO-type flow:
1) User in client UI.
2) Client directs user to API Provider (auth server).
3) User log-in in to auth server.
4) Authorize client app (/authorize).
5) Redirect to client providing auth code to redirect_uri for client.
6) Client uses auth code to obtain access_token and id_token (/token).

Abbreviated flow:
1) User is in API Provider UI.
2) User does activity which requires handoff to client.
3) Authorize client app (/authorize).
3) Redirect to client providing auth code to redirect_uri for client.
5) Client uses auth code to obtain access_token and id_token. (/token)

Note steps 3 - 5 in abbreviated flow correspond to steps 4 - 6 in standard flow. Since the user starts in the API+Identity Provider, it seems unnecessary to send user to third party so that they can start the flow.

I am wondering what pitfalls there are with the abbreviated flow - for example, there is no state parameter from the client, but the process is started by the API Provider, so I am not sure that there needs to be. Is there a more suitable flow to use than the abbreviated flow described above to hand off to a client app?